# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol common

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed the migration guide from Eclipse to Android Studio carefully and the only error that I am getting is "cannot resolve symbol common" and is happening on these lines:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The build tool (gradle) can't find the google_play_services library, that define the relevant classes.
Update your build.gradle file, so that it finds the library (at the right path):

**[EDIT 2: since 6.5, you can selectively add needed Google Play Services APIs ]**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-XXX:9.4.0'
}
```

**[EDIT: newer method, a 'native' support is now provided]**

Open SDK Manager, download and install Google Play Services and Google Repository
Edit build.gradle to add:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

**[Old method]**

Check that google-plays-services is a module in your project, and that its build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

In your module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
     compile project(':google-play-services')
}
```

Comment: The entire Play Services library has to be compiled?  That is huge.  Isn't there a subset?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You can now (not at the time of this answer) specify only a subset indeed. Relevant instructions at: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem solved using other way i.e. **apply plugin**.
Open your build.gradle(Module: app) file and add this line to the top below the first line.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and click on sync now. Problem solved.